# d3 highlighting nodes on mouseover causes unexpected behaviour when mouse taken off of svg space

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've written some code that highlights (via increased stroke width / change in stroke colour) node visualisations (some circles, some rects) and associated links/nodes when the user 'mouses down' on the node. The highlight disappears when the user 'mouses up'. This all works fine except when the node thats in a clicked state is dragged off of the svg space (technically I've constrained the visualisation to the svg space but obviously the mouse point isn't constrained) and released. The highlight then does not disappear as it should when the mouse button is released.

jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/hiwilson1/bga0wcLL/.

The method I chose to accomplish the highlighting was to manipulate the underlying objects associated with the clicked visualised node and then update the visualisations, which is all taken care of in the following onmousedown/onmouseup event function:

```
function highlight(d) {

    if (event.type == "mousedown") {
        d.highlight = 1;
        d.associatedLinks.forEach(function(link, i) {
            link.highlight = 1;
            link.source.highlight = 1;
            link.target.highlight = 1;
        })
    }
    else {
        d.highlight = 0;
        d.associatedLinks.forEach(function(link, i) {
            link.highlight = 0;
            link.source.highlight = 0;
            link.target.highlight = 0;
        })
    }

    svg.selectAll(".node .shape")
        .attr("stroke", function(d) { if (d.highlight == 1) { return "Black"}})
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.highlight == 1) ? 3 : 1 });           

    svg.selectAll(".link")
        .attr("stroke", function(d) { return (d.highlight == 1) ? "Black" : "Grey" })
        .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.highlight == 1) ? 3 : 1 });
}
```

Comment: Am i right in assuming you want to stop all drag functions when outside your bounding area ? Just not exactly sure what you would like to see.

Comment: Sorry I possibly didn't explain it well. Currently, if the user releases the mouse button outside of the svg space, the nodes/links retain their highlighted state (thick, black edges). The behaviour I want is that mouseup restores the nodes/links to their unhighlighted state irrespective of where the user releases the mouse button.

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to the `mousemove` event and make assumptions thereafter.  In the `highlight` function you will set the value of `lastHighlightedNode`

e.g.

```
lastHighlightedNode = null;
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

d3.select("body").on('mousemove', function () {
    if ((d3.mouse(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0])[0] == 0 || d3.mouse(document.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0])[1] == 0) && lastHighlightedNode != null) {
        highlight(lastHighlightedNode);
    };
});


.....



    function highlight(d) {
        lastHighlightedNode = d;

....
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bga0wcLL/1/

Comment: That fiddle isn't doing what I'm looking for. I want the mousedown event to trigger anywhere on the screen, essentially. Much like in the example here (though I can't see where in the code the author is achieving this) - http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116. Here, if you mousedown on a node, drag the cursor off of the svg space, and release, the highlighting effect cancels as desired. On my example however it remains.

Comment: Actually no I can see what the author has done. The mouseup event is on the window and a variable is used to control whether or not a node was pressed down upon on the preceeding mousedown. Thanks.